# Running the memz virus on a parallels vm: safe?

Tags: mac, windows, virtualization, parallels-desktop, virus

I have a copy of the memz virus, and have parallels windows vm. What I'm wondering, is if I run memz.exe/bin (not memz-clean.exe/bin), will I screw up the mac that I'm running the vm on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Parallels virtual machine is using a disk file for the guest operating system, and you haven't mapped your real hard drive into the vm - then no, in theory the Mac will not be screwed up.

The reason I write "in theory" is that there are a few practical concerns. Mainly, if you happen to have your hands on something that is not the original memz virus, but something else, it might do something unexpected. If the virus contains an exploit for Parallels usable from within the guest, it could break the isolation and tamper with your macOS installation. It is not very probably though.

Comment: The clean version of the memz virus which I got from the same .zip is the real one, so I'd expect that the destructive version is too. Also, would turning off any shared folders mac->windows theoretically make it safe?

Comment: In general, you definitely do not want to enable shared folders when testing viruses ofcourse. The memz virus works by overwriting the MBR though, so that isn't possible over shared folders.

Comment: IT WORKED AND WAS AWESOME AND DIDN'T SCREW UP MY COMPUTER